# Extend Jquery functions by functions which have subfunctions

Tags: jquery, ecmascript-5, extends

current situation:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    myFuncA:function(param){
    },
    myFuncB:function(param){
    },
    ....
});
```

calling this funcs:

```
$('any_selector').myFuncA();
```

But now i have many functions grouped to a specific type/element/whatever like this:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    Table_AddRow:function(param){
    },
    Table_RemoveRow:function(param){
    },
    Table_SortByColumn:function(param){
    },
    Table_ReNameColumn:function(param){
    },
    ....
    Select_AddElement:function(param){
    },
    Select_AddElement:function(param){
    },
    Select_RemoveElement:function(param){
    },
    Select_RenameElement:function(param){
    },
    Select_SetElements:function(param){
    },
    ....
});
```

This is just bad because the function names are pretty long and each function is beginning with:

```
if(!this.is('table')){
    return;
}
```

or

```
if(!this.is('select')){
    return;
}
```

Firstly I extend the jquery funcs with

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    Table:function(){
    }
    Select:function(){
    }
});
```

The function "table" will check if "this is a table" or not.

And then I would like to extend "Table" even further with the functions:

```
AddRow
RemoveRow
RenameColumn
...
```

Then i would like to call this functions like this:

```
$('any_selector').Table.AddRow();
$('any_selector').Table.RemoveRow();
...
```

or:

```
$('any_selector').Table.Foo();
$('any_selector').Table.DoSomethingElse();
```

or

```
$('any_selector').Select.AddItem();
$('any_selector').Select.RemoveItem();
```

because i have many functions related to some element types, i would like to group them, so that its way easier to find/use them.

And on top:

I want that the "Table" object checks, if its a table or not. And if it is a table, the sub function should be called (i dont want to implement the check for each function). If its not a table, i would like to make a small

```
console.log("wrong selector! .... ")
```

How can i do this?!
(i have to fix an old project ... so ... everything is written in ES5 and i need to group all the functions, because its just way to much.)

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
(function( $ ) {
  $.fn.Table = function(options) {
      var settings = $.extend({
          specialSort: function() {
              console.log('default');
          }
      }, options);

      return this.each(function() {
          settings.specialSort();
      });
  };
  
  
 $.fn.List = function(options) {
      var settings = $.extend({
          specialList: function() {
              console.log('default');
          }
      }, options);

      return this.each(function() {
          settings.specialList();
      });
  };
})( jQuery );

$('#output-Table').Table({ 
    specialSort: function() {
        console.log('custom-Table');
    }
});

$('#output-List').List({ 
    specialList: function() {
        console.log('custom-List');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="output-Table"></table>
<ul id="output-List"></ul>
```

Does this help you?

Comment: Well, its not what I'm looking for (or i misunderstood your solution). I would like to extend Jquery with a function called "Table" and this should be extended by another function "foo()" (or specialSort) and then i would like to call $('table#id').Table().foo() or $('table#id').Table.foo().
My goal is to group all functions which belong to html tables. And on top of that (if possible) the function table will check if its a table first. Because currently i have a ton of functions, which belong to tables, select, input, .... and each functions starts with "if this.is(table) " thats just bad.

Comment: So i want to group all table realated functions to a table object which has sub routines: $('table#id').Table().foo(). And ideally i would do the type check within the table object once and not in each function. Its a pretty old project :/

Comment: You have some example code for me? HTML/JS

Comment: i've just added better examples in the first post :)